# Windows file to TFS - How do I do it?

Tags: tfs

We're a small shop and have legacy VB6, Classic .ASP, .NET 1.2 - 3.51.  We installed the product successfully, but since depending on the code which needs changing we fire up the respective IDE Visual Studio x.  How do we go from no source control to TFS?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look at the [TFS 2008 Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fbd14eea-781f-45a1-8c46-9f6ba2f68bf0&DisplayLang=en).  One of the features that is available in the Power Tools is Windows Explorer integration, so you can get/checkout/checkin by right clicking the file(s).

Your other choices are to use the VS2008 / TFS 2008 client to do your SCM operations (which means you need to switch between multiple IDEs), or you could use the TF.EXE command line to do your SCM operations.

If I misread your question and you're asking how do you get your legacy code into TFS, you'll need to go into the TFS 2008 client and do the following:

- Map a workspace to a folder on your hard drive (or network).
- Copy your source to the folder.
- In TFS 2008, click on the "Add Files" button.
- Select the folder you just copied everything into.
- Add them.
- Check in.

Comment: we're now going with TFS 2010...any changes to your response?  Can you provide any advice on how we will compile some of the legacy (VB6, classic asp) code?  Will the debugging tools be available?  I hope MS provided a way to stay within 1 IDE.    BTW, thx for the steps above, that was exactly what we needed confirmation on.

Comment: No change to that process for VS/TFS 2010.  Since the classic ASP doesn't need compiled, you should be fine there.  The VB6 stuff gets a little more difficult.  You will, at a minimum need VB6 installed on the build machine.  Luckily for us, we've reduced the amount of VB6 down to a small handful of stuff that doesn't change, so we can just compile manually.